# How can I make uneven rows for a 2-column grid with Bootstrap/css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to eliminate the large gaps between the boxes in the left column, but I can't figure out how to do it. (see image)

I have an html template that is generating the div contents with a for-loop (row of 2 col-xs-6 columns), so I can't set static height values and float things (because the number of lines is always changing).

The code looks similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6" py:for="title, content in data">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                { title }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" py:for="line in content">
            { line }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know some css wizardry to help me out?

[image: Example of unwanted gaps]

Comment: Where is your code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: you don't want a 2 column grid in one container.  you want side-by-side containers each holding a single column grid.

Comment: @fnostro how would this work with dynamically generated data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time bootstrap doesn't support offset grids in a pinterest-like style.

Although, you can use bootstrap in combination with something like Masonry Grid to get the effect you are looking for:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Id use match height as it suits your question more. Here is what you do.
Download this and add to your scripts. Then add a class calldd match-height to your div columns which you want to be the same height.

https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height/blob/master/dist/jquery.matchHeight-min.js

```
$(function() {
    $('.match-height').matchHeight();
});
```

If any issues replace $ with jQuery

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this helps. I don't want to match the height of the boxes on the right, I want to push the left boxes up so there is less whitespace.

Comment: @stealthberry Sorry that was not what I read. - "eliminate the large gaps between the boxes." what you have replied to my answer with is much easier to understand so masonry is your best bet